# How do I check if my Air China eticket is business class?

Tags: tickets, air-china, business-class

I have just purchased an airchina ticket to NZ business class.  Where on my eticket can I find that it is indeed business class, please?

Comment: Does your e-ticket list any of “cabin”, “service class”, “fare”, “fare class”, “fare code” or “fare basis code”?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple ways:

1. You should have gotten a confirmation email for your booking. That email will list class of service
2. Log into your Air China account and look up your trip. The trip page will list class of service.
3. If you don't have an account, go here https://www.airchina.us/US/GB/booking/manage-my-trips/
4. If you have booked through a 3rd party booking agent, check your account there or your booking confirmation
5. If all else fails, call Air China.

The best way to look up your booking to use a the PNR (Passenger Name Record) which is a six digit combination of letters and numbers. The actual e-ticket number (long string of numbers starting with 999 for Air China) is less useful.

Comment: Note that instead of an explicitly readable text, the service class (cabin) may be designated by a code (single letter), or you may only have a fare class code (single letter as well, but more possible values) or a fare code (longer code), which are more difficult to map to service classes. If the “manage your booking” section (either on the ticket or operating airline’s website) allows seat selection in advance, it may also be a way to find the cabin.